# Fade Cycle on Divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, fade, cycle

I have some divs within a div which is within a div. The outer most div is `.major_data` then comes `.commitment_box` and then the sub-divs, `.commitment`. The commitments are in a fade cycle and so one `fadeOut()` and another `fadeIn()`. Here comes the problem, after the last div is `fadeOut()` the first don't come up. For more clearance see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NMSpx/).

**JS:**

```
function tick() {
    var $obj = $(".major_data .commitment_box .commitment");
    $obj.first().delay(1000).fadeOut(function () {
        $obj.first().insertAfter($obj.last());
        tick();
    });
}
tick();
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="major_data">
    <div class="commitment_box">
        <div class="commitment">
            <p>Alex:</p>
            <p>He's works great.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="commitment">
            <p>Alex 1:</p>
            <p>He's works great.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="commitment">
            <p>Alex 2:</p>
            <p>He's works great.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="commitment">
            <p>Alex 3:</p>
            <p>He's works great.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="commitment">
            <p>Alex 4:</p>
            <p>He's works great.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.major_data .commitment_box {
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.major_data .commitment_box .commitment p {
    display: inline-block;
}
.major_data .commitment_box .commitment p:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

You can see clearly in the fiddle what is the problem. After `Alex 4...` the first one doesnot come up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add a `fadeIn()` to the first `obj`. So after one cycle is gone, and you're hiding it, all your `div`s are set to `display:none`. Your code :

```
function tick() {
    var $obj = $(".major_data .commitment_box .commitment");
    $obj.first().fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut(function () {
        $obj.first().insertAfter($obj.last());
        tick();
    });
}
tick();
```

Updated demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/NMSpx/1/

Comment: How would you alter this script to make the cross fade? So they overlap?